# Why `operator->` in std::optional result in a UB when `*this` is not valid?

Tags: c++

According to Cppreference, [`optional::value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) on `std::nullopt` will throw, while [dereferencing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) an `optional` which is `std::nullopt` is UB.

I have tests, and seems the UB may not panic in some compilers, which is more horrible then just panic, so it is very harmful if mistakenly used. I am not say a UB is OK or meaningful, however, it is a bug, if it should happens, a wrong result is harder to debug than a panic.

```
struct I {
    int get() { return 1; }
};

void f() {
    try {
        std::optional<std::shared_ptr<I>> x = std::nullopt;
        printf("%d\n", (*x)->get()); // -----> UB
    }
    catch (std::bad_optional_access & e) {
        printf("it throws in f\n");
    }
}
```

My question is why `std::optional` is designed to result in a UB rather than also throw an exception like `value()` does in `operator*`/`operator->`?

Comment: because exceptions have a price. If you like you can pay for them by not using the dereference. If you don't like to pay for them you can also do it.

Comment: seems to aim at "Why does C++ not try to be a safe language? Why does it not try to protect me from mistakes?" Because thats not what C++ is. Other languages have that as a design goal, but thats different languages. C++ tries to make you pay only for what you need, and if there is a way to trade performance for safety then C++ lets you choose rather than forcing you to make runtime checks always

Comment: You may just as well ask why dereferencing a null pointer does not throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You have tests for UB? That seems to indicate that you don't understand what it means, because there is exactly nothing you can rely on in case of UB, not even that it fails in some way.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  I just want to show you that if this UB happens, it does more horrible thing than burning your computer out. It returns a random result which could be hard to diagnose.

Comment: @calvin you can use sanitizers and static code analysis. UB is by definition those mistakes that are not diagnosed by your compiler

Comment: C++ will not babysit you. It will allow you to write code that is efficient. One of C++'s tennets is : don't pay for what you don't use. Since checking is not always needed it is NOT by default included in the normal program flow.

Comment: It's not just about cost but also about uniformity; an invalid dereference always has undefined behaviour. Introducing special cases is very often a bad idea.

Comment: You can always explicitly call `has_value()` before dereferencing

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai    That's not quite true.   One property of UB, by definition, is that the C++ standard does not *require* a diagnostic.  Equally, implementations are not forbidden from issuing a diagnostic - but some real-world compilers can and do diagnose some forms of UB (albeit, not by default - e.g. `-Wall` can and does coerce gcc and clang compilers to issue warnings for *some* forms of UB).

Comment: @Peter right, I was imprecise. I meant, UB is by definition what the compiler is not *required* to diagnose.

Comment: Note that libstdc++ and MSVC STL (the standard libraries of GCC and MSVC respectively) will catch this if you enable the respective debug macros: `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and `-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` (or `=1`).

Comment: I think problem is you misunderstood what UB is. UB doesn't mean "crash" it means anything can happen, even [daemons can fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core reason is the [Zero overhead principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle) which has underpinned the development and evolution of every C++ standard.

As stated in the link, this principle requires:

- You (the developer) don't pay for what you don't use.
- What you do use is just as efficient as what you could reasonably write by hand.

When it comes to evolution of the C++ standard library and features in it - including `std::optional` - this principle often has the effect of there being two ways of achieving some things

- There is an "unsafe" option which, if misused, results in undefined behaviour but this, if used skillfully, costs less (e.g. less performance hit, less memory usage).
- There is *also* a costly option that has no undefined behaviour.

The only times when a library feature does not provide both the "safe" and "unsafe" options is if "safety" comes with zero cost.   In practice, when there is a cost, the C++ standard allows a developer the freedom to *decide* whether to code for maximum safety or for minimum cost.

In other words, the C++ standard requires the developer to deliberately make an engineering trade-off, rather than imposing any specific choice on the developer.

This is a different philosophy from some other programming languages that mandate "safety" (in various forms) but (almost) always force a developer to accept the overheads (e.g. resource usage, runtime performance).

In the context of this question,

- `std::optional::operator *()` is the "unsafe" option that avoids the overhead (of checking and throwing an exception) but requires the developer accept and manage the potential impact of introducing undefined behaviour.
- `std::optional::value()` is the "safe" option in which there is no undefined behaviour, but the implementation of `std::optional::value()` must explicitly do a check in order to throw an exception on `std::nullopt`.   The need to do a check, and the throwing of an exception, is the cost for avoiding undefined behaviour.   A developer who elects to use this option must accept and/or manage the associated costs of safety.

As I said above, it is the developer's freedom (and, with freedom comes responsibility) to make the choice of approach they use.   The C++ standard allows the choice, but does not impose one option or the other on the developer.

Answer (score 9):

Because C++ does not make you pay for things that you do not need.

The check if `std::optional` holds a value has a cost. It's only a simple condition, and it's only one branch, but when you are certain that there is a value and when you need to access the value often, that condition and branch can be significant.

If you know for sure that the optional contains a value, there is no need to check if it contains a value.

```
 // ...
 std::optional<int> x = 42; 
 for (int i=0;i<100000; ++i) {
          foo(*x);
 }
```

It would be a waste of resources to check in every single iteration whether `x` does contain an `int`. Other times you want an exception being thrown and then you can use `value()`.

Comment: And if you want the test and a no-exception guarantee, you can use `x.has_value()` to test manually and `*x` to access

Comment: To be fair, a modern optimising compiler could probably hoist the check out of the loop in the simple case you’ve shown. But as soon as `x` is no longer local (or any of a thousand other things change) the compiler could no longer prove that `foo` didn’t modify `x`, and thus couldn’t optimise this any more. (Okay, I just checked: in this simple case the compiler doesn’t even bother constructing a `std::optional` object.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph not always the compiler can see through everything. A simple example is necessarily much simpler to optimize than a real case. Suppose the loop is inside some function `bar(std::optional<int>)` that for some reason cannot be inlined

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Right, that’s what my comment says.